# Textures loads in editor but not in standalone (appears pink)

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I'm using an asset named **Simple Obj**, that allows me to **import an obj, their materials and the textures associate**. This works fine in my editor but not in my standalone.
My **OBJ are not in my resources file**, I take it from another file with the WWW method.

Here's how I do it, t*his download my OBJ, create a Gameobject and place it in my scene* :

```
private IEnumerator DownloadAndImportAllInBackground(string url, Plane newPlane)
{
    string objString = null;
    string mtlString = null;
    Hashtable textures = null;
    GameObject planeObject = null;
    bool gameObjectPerGroup = false;
    bool subMeshPerGroup = false;
    bool usesRightHanded = true;

    yield return StartCoroutine(DownloadFile(url, retval => objString = retval));
        yield return StartCoroutine(DownloadFile(url.Substring(0, url.Length - 4) + ".mtl", retval => mtlString = retval));
        if (mtlString != null && mtlString.Length > 0)
        {
            string path = url;
            int lastSlash = path.LastIndexOf('/', path.Length - 1);
            if (lastSlash >= 0) path = path.Substring(0, lastSlash + 1);
            Hashtable[] mtls = ObjImporter.ImportMaterialSpecs(mtlString);
            for (int i = 0; i < mtls.Length; i++)
            {
                if (mtls[i].ContainsKey("mainTexName"))
                {
                    Texture2D texture = null;
                    string texUrl = path + mtls[i]["mainTexName"];
                    yield return StartCoroutine(DownloadTexture(texUrl, retval => texture = retval));
                    if (texture != null)
                    {
                        if (textures == null) textures = new Hashtable();
                        textures[mtls[i]["mainTexName"]] = texture;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    yield return StartCoroutine(DownloadFile(url, retval => objString = retval));

    if (objString != null && objString.Length > 0)
    {
        yield return StartCoroutine(ObjImporter.ImportInBackground(objString, mtlString, textures, retval => planeObject = retval, gameObjectPerGroup, subMeshPerGroup, usesRightHanded));
        planeObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.0005f, 0.0005f, 0.0005f);
        if (planeObject == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Null gameobject");
        }
        planeObject.name = newPlane.Callsign;
        planeObject.transform.position = new Vector3((float)newPlane.X, (float)newPlane.Afl / (3.2808f * 1852f), (float)newPlane.Y);
        planeObject.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, -180 + newPlane.Heading, 0);
        planeId_Object_Dictionnary.Add(newPlane.Flight, planeObject);
    }

}
```

And here's what happen in my **editor/standalone** :
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pink appearance means your build have missing material assignment on the mesh renderer component or missing shader in the build.

If you are assigning materials or shaders at runtime make sure you include the shader in the build.

You can force unity to include any shader by adding it to the list in
**Edit/Project Settings/Graphics**

[image]

Comment: I have the same thing than you, is there something more I should include ?

Comment: What shader are you using on these models? Make sure is on the list.

Comment: Ok I found the solution, thanks for your help, if you want to slightly improve your answer, I have to watch all the shaders that were use in my editor mode and include it in my shaders for the standalone. To do so, I save my preloaded shader in an asset and look what were the shaders in this asset. I don't know if i'm clear ?