# Altering materials shows as pink on Samsung TV

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, samsung-smart-tv

I'm making an app for the Samsung TV, using Unitys build > Samsung TV.

I have a bunch of primitive boxes where I've altered the materials mainTexture to an atlas and the meshfilters uv to the given uv from the PackTextures method.

```
            Texture2D[] allCubeTextures = new Texture2D[] { app.GetComponentInChildren<Image>().mainTexture as Texture2D, Resources.Load<Texture2D>("Black"), Resources.Load<Texture2D>("Black"), Resources.Load<Texture2D>("Black"), Resources.Load<Texture2D>("Black"), Resources.Load<Texture2D>("Black") };
            Texture2D textureAtlas = new Texture2D(2, 2);
            Rect[] atlasUvs = textureAtlas.PackTextures(allCubeTextures, 200);
            icon.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = textureAtlas;
            Vector2[] uv = new Vector2[6 * 4];
            for (int i = 0; i < atlasUvs.Length; i++)
            {
                int j = i * 4;
                uv[j] = new Vector2(atlasUvs[i].xMin, atlasUvs[i].yMin);
                uv[j + 1] = new Vector2(atlasUvs[i].xMax, atlasUvs[i].yMin);
                uv[j + 2] = new Vector2(atlasUvs[i].xMin, atlasUvs[i].yMax);
                uv[j + 3] = new Vector2(atlasUvs[i].xMax, atlasUvs[i].yMax);
            }
            Mesh mesh = icon.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
            mesh.uv = uv;
```

It looks all good and fine in the editor, however, whenever I test on a Samsung TV, the boxes are all pink (as if they are broken shaders).

Before editing the mainTexture to an atlas texture, I used unitys standard uv. This worked, but my texture was on all sides, instead of how my atlas handles it now. This is why I'm thinking it may be related to that.

In my attempt to wrap my head around this error I've also tried with a bunch of different shaders, with no different result.

Is it just that Samsung TV doesn't support this implementation of my texture?

The Samsung TV log:

```
Game_Main:209] GPlayer PFM Ver : (1001) 
Failed to create random directory /tmp/pulseaudio/pulse-XswsA4ySxtTi: Permission denied
Mono path[0] = '/opt/storage/usb/sda1/f0caae903700866889117406a674369e6e82bef3/resources/Data/Managed'
Mono config path = '/opt/storage/usb/sda1/f0caae903700866889117406a674369e6e82bef3/resources/Data/Managed'
using 32 bit
using 24 bit depth
Renderer: 
Vendor:   ARM
Version:  OpenGL ES 2.0
GLES:     2
GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_EXT_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_sub_texture GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_depth24 GL_ARM_rgba8 GL_ARM_mali_shader_binary GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_ARM_mali_program_binary GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod GL_EXT_robustness GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_KHR_debug GL_ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch GL_ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_depth_stencil GL_OES_mapbuffer
OPENGL LOG: Creating OpenGL ES 2.0 graphics device ; Context level  <OpenGL ES 2.0> ; Context handle 1073741825
Initialize engine version: 5.4.1f1 (649f48bbbf0f)
Failed to create random directory /tmp/pulseaudio/pulse-Ivi10nSJCUJP: Permission denied
Failed to create random directory /tmp/pulseaudio/pulse-YonkWqDHH005: Permission denied
Not enough permissions to set priority (must be root)Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
Platform assembly: /opt/storage/usb/sda1/f0caae903700866889117406a674369e6e82bef3/resources/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading /opt/storage/usb/sda1/f0caae903700866889117406a674369e6e82bef3/resources/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: /opt/storage/usb/sda1/f0caae903700866889117406a674369e6e82bef3/resources/Data/Managed/User/Assembly-CSharp.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading /opt/storage/usb/sda1/f0caae903700866889117406a674369e6e82bef3/resources/Data/Managed/User/Assembly-CSharp.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: /opt/storage/usb/sda1/f0caae903700866889117406a674369e6e82bef3/resources/Data/Managed/User/UnityEngine.UI.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading /opt/storage/usb/sda1/f0caae903700866889117406a674369e6e82bef3/resources/Data/Managed/User/UnityEngine.UI.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: /opt/storage/usb/sda1/f0caae903700866889117406a674369e6e82bef3/resources/Data/Managed/User/UnityEngine.Networking.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading /opt/storage/usb/sda1/f0caae903700866889117406a674369e6e82bef3/resources/Data/Managed/User/UnityEngine.Networking.dll into Unity Child Domain
- Completed reload, in  0.133 seconds
Platform assembly: /opt/storage/usb/sda1/f0caae903700866889117406a674369e6e82bef3/resources/Data/Managed/System.Core.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: /opt/storage/usb/sda1/f0caae903700866889117406a674369e6e82bef3/resources/Data/Managed/System.dll (this message is harmless)
-------- Shader compilation failed
#version 100
#extension GL_EXT_frag_depth : enable
precision mediump float;
uniform highp vec4 _ProjectionParams;
uniform highp vec4 _ZBufferParams;
uniform highp mat4 unity_CameraToWorld;
uniform highp mat4 _NonJitteredVP;
uniform highp mat4 _PreviousVP;
uniform highp sampler2D _CameraDepthTexture;
varying highp vec2 xlv_TEXCOORD0;
varying highp vec3 xlv_TEXCOORD1;
void main ()
{
  highp vec4 tmpvar_1;
  tmpvar_1 = texture2D (_CameraDepthTexture, xlv_TEXCOORD0);
  mediump vec2 tmpvar_2;
  highp vec4 tmpvar_3;
  tmpvar_3.w = 1.0;
  tmpvar_3.xyz = ((xlv_TEXCOORD1 * (_ProjectionParams.z / xlv_TEXCOORD1.z)) * (1.0/((
    (_ZBufferParams.x * tmpvar_1.x)
   + _ZBufferParams.y))));
  highp vec4 tmpvar_4;
  tmpvar_4 = (unity_CameraToWorld * tmpvar_3);
  highp vec4 tmpvar_5;
  tmpvar_5 = (_PreviousVP * tmpvar_4);
  highp vec4 tmpvar_6;
  tmpvar_6 = (_NonJitteredVP * tmpvar_4);
  highp vec2 tmpvar_7;
  tmpvar_7 = (((tmpvar_5.xy / tmpvar_5.w) + 1.0) / 2.0);
  highp vec2 tmpvar_8;
  tmpvar_8 = (((tmpvar_6.xy / tmpvar_6.w) + 1.0) / 2.0);
  tmpvar_2 = (tmpvar_8 - tmpvar_7);
  mediump vec4 tmpvar_9;
  tmpvar_9.zw = vec2(0.0, 1.0);
  tmpvar_9.xy = tmpvar_2;
  gl_FragDepthEXT = tmpvar_1.x;
  gl_FragData[0] = tmpvar_9;
}
-------- failed compiling:
fragment evaluation shader
0:4: P0003: Extension 'GL_EXT_frag_depth' not supported
0:6: P0004: High precision not supported, instead compiling high precision as medium precision
0:38: L0002: Undeclared variable 'gl_FragDepthEXT'
Note: Creation of internal variant of shader 'Hidden/Internal-MotionVectors' failed.
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/Internal-MotionVectors' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/Internal-MotionVectors' - Setting to default shader.
UnloadTime: 4.557000 ms
Unloading 4 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)

Unloading 8 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 844.
Total: 4.570000 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.397000 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.061000 ms MarkObjects: 3.410000 ms  DeleteObjects: 0.691000 ms)

Unloading 2 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)

Unloading 94 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 1056.
Total: 16.380001 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.444000 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.075000 ms MarkObjects: 3.665000 ms  DeleteObjects: 12.190001 ms)

[UnityLauncher] Stop Game
```

Edit:
After doing some further digging I think my problem is somewhat related to:
[Textures loads in editor but not in standalone (appears pink)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909567/textures-loads-in-editor-but-not-in-standalone-appears-pink?rq=1)
I don't quite get the solution though. I have no options when choosing preloded shaders. Also, I'm using standard shaders, so I wouldn't think this would be an issue.

Edit 2:
Okay, after some more research I came across this post: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/939160/getting-pink-textures-in-build.html
It seems I have to add my shader (Unlit/Texture) to the always included shaders. This however only changes the box to white instead of pink. Just as Legacy/Diffuse did, as it's also in the always included shaders.

Comment: What year is the Samsung make and what is the model number?

Comment: Tested on both a 15 and 16 model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found the solution.

As written in the link in edit 1, I had to both include the shader in the "Always Included Shaders" under Edit>Project Settings>Graphics. 
I then had to Save the ShaderVariant to my assets folder, and add that variant to the "Shader Preloading".

Comment: Nice. Problems like these are hard to find fix for. Congrats!

Answer (score 1):

I notice a line in the SamsungTV log: `-------- Shader compilation failed`
Your shader failed to compile so the pink stuff is an expected behavior.

A shader can compile and run well on a device but fails on others. That's normal. If you are using built-in Standard shader please report a bug to Unit otherwise include a SubShader in your shader which supports SamsungTV device.

Pay attention to this part too:

```
fragment evaluation shader
0:4: P0003: Extension 'GL_EXT_frag_depth' not supported
0:6: P0004: High precision not supported, instead compiling high precision as medium precision
0:38: L0002: Undeclared variable 'gl_FragDepthEXT'
Note: Creation of internal variant of shader 'Hidden/Internal-MotionVectors' failed.
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/Internal-MotionVectors' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/Internal-MotionVectors' - Setting to default shader.
```

From what I can see, your shader uses an unsupported library called `GL_EXT_frag_depth` which leads to a variable `gl_FragDepthEXT` of that type undeclared.

Comment: I have tried with Unlit/Textures, Legacy/Diffuse, Standard, Mobile/Unlit and Mobile Diffuse. All pink, but Legacy/Diffuse. That one is white.
I saw what you saw, and tested with different shaders, as written in OP.
No different result. That's why my conclusion is that it must be something with my texture atlas. I just can't see what.